# Why doesn't Ahab have the right to just seize land as he see fits?

Tags: malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, king-saul

Ahab wanted a land from Nabot. Nabot doesn't want to sell. Well, Ahab is a king.

So Ahab frames Nabot for treason, kills him, and takes his land. G-d gets upset and curses Ahab and his descendants.

If Saul can kill the high priests and is still a tzadik, why can't Ahab?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22709/759

Comment: I hope you notice that Ahab didn't assert his royal authority but lied and cheated to kill off Naboth. That is not what Saul did when he used his royal authority to quell what was in his eyes a rebellion.

Comment: See Tosfos ד"ה מלך to [Sanhedrin 20b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=20b&format=pdf)

Comment: @ba That looks like an answer.

Comment: It doesn't answer why this case is different from that of Sha'ul (which this question assumes).

Comment: I don't see, Jim Thio, why you bring Saul into it. Why not just ask why Ahab, as king, can't take the land? What does murder of _Nov_-dwellers have to do with anything?

Comment: Because it seems that Saul's sin is far greater than Ahab, killing Nov, consulting the death, yet he is a Tzadik. All Ahab did is exercising eminent domain that even US government do, yet it's not. Ahab even offer fair price. It's like what the jews did to many palestines. The difference is that many palestines are actually eager to sell if not because of some laws preventing it. Which seems to be the case for Nabot either.

Comment: @JimThio "All Ahab did is...". Do you mean besides worship the Ba'al, build an alter for it, make an Asherah( [Kings I 16:31-33](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a16.htm)), give Jezebel the freedom to kill off "the prophets of the LORD"([ibid. 18:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a18.htm#4)), and generally do "yet more to provoke the LORD, the God of Israel, than all the kings of Israel that were before him"(ibid 16:33)?

Answer (score 5):

[Rambam, The Laws of Kings and Wars, 3:8 (Chabad.org)](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188347/jewish/Chapter-3.htm)

> Anyone who rebels against a king of Israel may be executed by the king…

Shaul was considered righteous since he believed he was putting down a rebellion.

> The king may only execute people by decapitation. ……However, he may not confiscate property. If he does, it is considered theft.

This is why Achav couldn't just take the property.

[Rambam ibid. 4:9 (Chabad.org)](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188348/jewish/Chapter-4.htm):

> The property of all those executed by the king, belongs to the king. Similarly, all the treasures belonging to the kings of the kingdoms which he conquers become the property of the king.

So Achav (or Izevel) thought that by scheming to have Navos framed and killed, they could legally take his property. However, G-d was not fooled, and he punished Achav and Izevel for their evil.

---

Side note: Achav may not have been considered a king at all, halachicly.

[Rambam ibid. 1:8 (Chabad.org)](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188345/jewish/Chapter-1.htm)

> If a prophet appoints a king from any other tribe of Israel and that king follows the path of Torah and mitzvot and fights the wars of God, he is considered as a king, and all the commandments associated with the monarchy apply to him.

Comment: But http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a08.htm#14

Comment: @DoubleAA Good question! [Rambam ibid 4:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188348/jewish/Chapter-4.htm) _"He may take fields, olive groves, and vineyards for his servants when they go to war and allow them to commandeer these places if they have no source of nurture other than them. He must pay for what is taken. This is stated in ibid.:14: 'He shall take your good fields, vineyards, and olive groves and give them to his servants."_

Comment: Yap, he may take fields. In fact, why bother killing Nabot? Why not just go to war somewhere (can't believe I am suggesting this) so he has a legal reason to seize fields? I really got to check Rabam's reasoning. It looks a lot like after the fact justification rather than objective analysis.

Comment: @JimThio Rambam isn't talking about this story at all. He's talking about the laws of what _all_ Jewish kings may and may not do.

Comment: I guess owning a property must be very dangerous in ancient time. If I am too rich, any king will have plenty of interest to kill me so he can seize my money like contemporary civil forfeiture in US. Oh he needs a probable cause. Well, Saul's probable cause is also pretty slight. If a high priest told me that he doesn't know David is Saul's enemy, that give rise to a lot of reasonable doubt given that Saul hasn't told the Nov.

Comment: @JimThio Also, it would have to be a war near Navos' field, Ramabam says: _" if they have no source of nurture other than them"_. Navos' field was next door to Achav's palace, so that seems unlikely.

Comment: @JimThio Owning too much or being rich is dangerous _whenever_ there is a powerful tyrant who can kill/imprison you to take it. Not just in ancient times. See Russia for example.

Comment: @HodofHod Good find in Rambam. IIRC though that pasuk is subject to a machloket rishonim in terms of how it actually applies.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damocles#The_sword_of_Damocles

Comment: A king is just a businessman that bet his blood rather than just money.