# Can a King execute Kohen Gadol that he thinks is מורד במלכות?

Tags: halacha, malchut-royalty, capital-punishment, kohen-gadol

While Kohen Gadol is a citizen, he belongs to a different "authority" that a King is obligated to respect (see Rambam Melachim 2, 5):

> "אבל כהן גדול אינו בא לפני המלך אלא אם רצה ואינו עומד לפניו
>   אלא המלך עומד לפני כהן גדול שנאמר ולפני אלעזר הכהן יעמוד"

While we read that factually [Saul killed the city of Nov](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.22.16?lang=he) (thnks Joel) but can a King **Halachicly** execute Kohen Gadol that he thinks is מורד במלכות?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.2.26?lang=he

Comment: Also Joash killing Jehoiada's son Zechariah in 2 Chronicles 24.  Probably not the best idea since retribution came fast to Joash.

Comment: Re: the king's obligation to respect the _Kohen Gadol_ in the _Mishneh Torah_: Later on it says (in [translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188346/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-2.htm)): "When does the above apply? When the king is alone in his palace. Then, in private, before his servants, he should behave in this fashion. However, in public, before the people at large, he should not conduct himself in this manner. He should not stand before anyone ... in order that the awe of him will be implanted in everyone's hearts."

Comment: Related (on the subject of Saul killing the city of Nov): [How was Saul a Tzadik if he wiped out Nov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22709/1368)?